# Spree::OrderPopulator accessing outside of store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

On Rails 4.1 .. being new to Spree 2-3-stable and experimenting with various things.  My test store works fine and now I would am trying and integrate it into my application which is a booking site.

On my Bookings calendar I would like users to click on a booking link and have that auto populate their cart, then show their cart directly.

So assuming I have a spree product, and a variant existing in the database, and the current_user is logged in (ie spree_current_user exists) .. I thought this would be possible but it seems it will not even create the populator.

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  def add_booking_to_cart        
    populator = Spree::OrderPopulator.new Spree::Order.current_order(create_order_if_necessary: true), current_currency
    # .. get variant related to booking
    # .. add varient to populator
  end
  #... rest of bookings controller
 end

Errors out with:
NoMethodError - undefined method `current_order' for #<Class:0x00000007d4fc68>:
```

I am attempting to do a similar thing to what Will is doing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22723948/spreeorderpopulator-populate-ordering-two-items-when-one-requested/24751823#24751823) but am getting the error **undefined method on current_order object**.  My understanding of the code is that it should create a new order if necessary, ie if one does not exist.  No sure what do to here? Any pointer would be greatly aprecieated.

https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/2-3-stable/frontend/app/controllers/spree/orders_controller.rb#L46

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work your controller needs to extend `Spree::StoreController`

```
class BookingController < Spree::StoreController
```

This is where the method is defined in Spree:
https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/lib/spree/core/controller_helpers/order.rb

Also, you might need to have a `before_filter :set_current_order`.